# If a pet has/uses an artifact, are the benefits of that artifact conferred to the pet?

Tags: nethack

I have a pet Mindflayer and am trying to equip him for the things that kill MFs (mainly, jellies).  So far, he has a +1 SDSM and an alchemy smock(AcidR for Ochre Js and Spotted Js). The wiki recs YDSM for AR, but I had these available. I also have a +3 Frost Brand that I'm unlikely to use, and I'm wondering if the ColdR will protect from Blue Jellies?

Comment: Note: Upon further research, I found that the alchemy smock (apron) does NOT confer Acid Resistance to monsters (only PR).  So, apparently, only yellow DScalesMail are the only way to protect pets (particularly MFs) from acid short of genociding  jellies.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your general question is yes, whatever the pet has is put into his stats and such.